# Batch File For loop outputs same info for each loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm no expert, just pushing through but I can't figure this out. I expect each text of output to be different but it is the same,

I have a bunch of text files I am passing to GSAR.exe which edits a python script and then executes it, outputting to a text file. it seems to loop but every output text contains the same text. Here is the code. Please keep in mind that a lot of this was guesswork and trial and error.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*_RGB.txt) do (
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set content=
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('type "*_RGB.txt"') do (set content=!content! %%D

_GSAR.EXE -s"129, 88, 47" -r"!content!" -o "_color.py"
"C:\Users\%MYname%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe" _color.py > "%%~na_HSV.txt")
)
```

Comment: Your `for /f` loop is coded to save every line as one string to a variable named `content`. As you're performing your `GSAR` command against in within that loop, you're running it against `line1` then `line1 line2` then `line1 line2 line3` etc…. I would suggest that you perhaps try removing the `set` line, and replacing `!content!` with `%%D`. If you're supposed to be sending each line as one string however, just move your closing parenthesis up three lines!

Comment: There is only one line in the text and it successfully passes to gsar. the output is accurate but should be different. I am assuming I somehow have to reset !content! as it seems both outputs are from the first file. I have tried %%D but will again and try your other suggestion.

Comment: There might be at the end, but in order to get there it's running a command for each line of each text file, which I'm sure is unwanted behavior! If there's only ever going to be one line in the file, you should change your `for /f` loop, to just `(set "content=%%D"`

Comment: As I said. There is only one line of text to run and the results are from the first file. It's not sending the info from the second file to GSAR. I tried both suggestions one at a time and together and still have the same results. Forgive me if I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: If I check the _color.py file it contains the info from the first text file not the last. My intention is that it is edited each pass.

Comment: Duimon, I'm just telling you how it's currently coded, I'm not answering whatever your question is, because I clearly saw an issue with your code, and thought you may want to know. I'm sorry, if you know better! They're not the only issue with your code either! like depending upon the number of iterations a potential stack overflow. And that's without asking, why you haven't looked into using GSAR with a file input, as you appear to be extracting lines from a file anyhow.

Comment: If you explain the task, instead, it would help. Your code is contradictory and therefore I'm unable to determine your task by simply reading it.

Comment: As I said, I am a rookie and will probably break something. I will look into the GSAR file input.  The text files contain RGB color values. The python script calculates HSV values and prints them but you can't pass a value to the python script, it has to be coded in, so I am editing the RGB value in the python script with the info from the text file. I would like the output to be named the same as the *,RGB but appended by _HSV. I will potentially run this against over 1000 files.

Comment: Just guessung, but maybe the closing `)` should be moved two lines up?

Answer (score 0):

You process all files (`type *_RGB.txt`) for each file; that's not what you want. You want to process just each file. The following should work for you (if your parameter syntax for `_GSAR.EXE` is correct; I can't verfiy):

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*_RGB.txt) do (
  for /F "usebackq delims=" %%D in ("%%a") do (
    _GSAR.EXE -s"129, 88, 47" -r"%%D" -o "_color.py"  
    "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe" _color.py > "%%~na_HSV.txt")
)
```

Comment: I can see how that cleans it up but it passes the name of the *_RGB.txt not the contents.

Comment: Well. That solved that problem, but, we are back at the beginning. The python script is only being executed once... all the outputs contain the value from the first *_RGB.txt.

Comment: I don't know GSAR, but I noticed there is a different parameter format: `/s"..."` and `/r"..."` but `/o<space>"..."`. Might that be a problem?

Comment: Nope. if you remove the space it thinks the _color.py is an argument not a target file. Funny thing is before your edit the python script was executed twice. (Currently testing on two *_RGB.txt)

Comment: There are two lines I have no idea what they are doing or supposed to do. So please run that code without `@echo off` and show the output (by editing it into your question) and explain how it differs from what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from Stephan I came up with this...

```
@echo off
   for %%a in (*_RGB.txt) do (
     for /F "usebackq delims=" %%D in ("%%a") do (
       set file=%%D
       set file_shortname=%%~na_HSV.txt
       call :parse_file)
   )

   goto :EOF

   :parse_file
       copy _temp_color.py _color.py
       _GSAR.EXE -s"129, 88, 47" -r"%file%" -o "_color.py"  
       "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe" _color.py > "%file_shortname%"
      del /f /q _color.py

   goto :EOF
```

_color.py was being changed so the subsequent searches were failing. Doh!!